# Resource is not a Drawable Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, exception, android-drawable, android-resources

Getting this error since I started changing device for testing. Did some searching and none of it help because they are outdated. Any help is appreciated!

**xml file**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/loginpanel"
    android:layout_width="491px"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="146dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/loginpanel"

    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/numpanel2"
    android:layout_width="388px"
    android:layout_height="452px"
    android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="368dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/numpanel1"
    android:alpha="0.95"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**These are my folders, there's no drawable-v24 folder**

[image]

Comment: Make sure your `loginpanel` and `numpanel1` images is inside `drawable` folder not inside `drawable-v24` folder

Comment: Please recheck @NileshRathod

Comment: What are `loginpanel` and `numpanel1` ?

Comment: There's a `(v24)` tag with the file name of `loginpanel` and `numpanel1` @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: Ok, but the question is different. What are (the content) not where are.

Comment: They're both `.jpg` files @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: @kwestionable move your both images `loginpanel` and `numpanel1` inside  `drawable` just copy paste from `drawable-v24` to `drawable` folder

Comment: @kwestionable Read the Nilesh comment.

Comment: They're already in the `drawable` folder @NileshRathod, there's no `drawable-v24`

Comment: @kwestionable The "tag" v24 means that these files are located in the folder drawable-v24. You are using the Android View. If you switch to Project View you can see this folder.

Comment: found it guys, thanks a lot! Make your comments as answers so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your `loginpanel` and `numpanel1` images is inside drawable folder not inside `drawable-v24` folder

move your both images `loginpanel` and `numpanel1` inside `drawable`

just copy-paste from `drawable-v24` to `drawable` folder it will work