# Error inflating class ImageButton Stops app from starting

Tags: android, android-xml, android-inflate

My app fails to start because of Error inflating class ImageButton, Because of this the phone says "app has stopped" Etc.
I am using firebase test lab to debug the problem

the Errors occur on samsung devices specifically A20, s7 Edge , s7(tested with firebase same problem)

I am new to android and have tried many solutions from google and SO none have worked sofar

Here is the error report on firebase

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smartpractice.smartpracticesmartapp/com.smartpractice.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #117: Binary XML file line #117: Error inflating class ImageButton
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.smartpractice.smartpracticesmartapp, PID: 26921
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smartpractice.smartpracticesmartapp/com.smartpractice.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #117: Binary XML file line #117: Error inflating class ImageButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #117: Binary XML file line #117: Error inflating class ImageButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.smartpractice.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #117: Error inflating class ImageButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070089
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2558)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
    at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:79)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:69)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:202)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:122)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:758)
```

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ic_launcher_background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:id="@+id/flexboxLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:alignContent="stretch"
        app:alignItems="stretch"
        app:flexWrap="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.863"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/welcome_to_smartpractice"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
            app:layout_alignSelf="baseline"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="100dp"
            tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|fill_vertical"
            android:text="@string/docsharesmart"
            android:textColor="@color/ic_launcher_background"
            app:layout_alignSelf="flex_end"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:alignContent="center"
        app:alignItems="stretch"
        app:flexDirection="row"
        app:flexWrap="nowrap"
        app:justifyContent="space_between"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo1"
            app:layout_alignSelf="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/smartpractice_logo_02"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-46dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/LoginScreen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/loginscreen"
            app:layout_alignSelf="center"
            app:layout_wrapBefore="false"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="248dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="134dp" />


    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:id="@+id/flexboxLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:alignContent="stretch"
        app:alignItems="stretch"
        app:flexWrap="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/flexboxLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.146">
```

Here is line 117 from the error

```
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/UploadButton"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="209dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/flexboxLayout"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/upload_files_upload"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />


    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="185dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874882/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-error-inflating-class-fragment)

Comment: The error is related to the image/background being loaded

Comment: @Bosco Not the same at all

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970130/resource-is-not-a-drawable-resourcesnotfoundexception/57970576#57970576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means upload_files_upload is not found in `drawble` folder, well this can be a case, where your file may present in `drawable-24` but not in `drawble` folder, in that case this problem still arise. The point is **your file must be in all `drawble` folder.**

Comment: I just have one drawable folder, That is "Drawable" Must I add new drawable folders or what

Comment: @RubenMeiring No, that is not needed. Will try remove this line: app:srcCompat="@drawable/upload_files_upload" and build your project again. Let me know what happens

Comment: the button disapears it is an imagebutton and that removes the image

Comment: There might be a problem with your image, wil try loading different image in your ImageButton

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error is that the `upload_files_upload` is not in your `drawable` folder :

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/UploadButton"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="209dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/flexboxLayout" 
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/upload_files_upload"// this line
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
```

Comment: I only have the one drawable folder and the app works on several devices on my phone and several of my colleagues phones

Comment: Is your upload_files_upload vector drawable?

Comment: Yes it is, will that cause an issue??, It is in PNG format if that will make a diffrence

Comment: did you define defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }   in your build.gradle?

Comment: Yes, I have, the thing is the app works on some phones and some not, its very confusing

Comment: What is the Android version of your phone?

Comment: put this line at the beginning of the activity that will use the resource may help :

static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }

Comment: android 9, it works n several other phones asweel wich the android versions i am not sure of, BUT I changed   app:srcCompat="@drawable/upload_files_upload"//  to android:src="@drawable/upload_files_upload" and that solved the issue ]

Comment: that's fine ! and see this image :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N5Ab.png

Answer (score 0):

I have solved The Issue I changed app:srcCompat="@drawable/upload_files_upload"// to android:src="@drawable/upload_files_upload"
So the problem was by app:srcCompat I changed it to Android:src and it works fine now